# Get SharePoint storage used by the sites via powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, storage

I want to get the total number of storage used by SharePoint sites.
[image]

I can get the total storage allocated to SharePoint organisation which I can do by using the following:

```
Get-SPOTenant | Select-Object StorageQuota
```

But I can't find a command to get storage used by the sites in total.
I can loop through all the sites and add the storage used by each site to get the total storage used by SharePoint. However, I was looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such cmdlet to get the total storage of all sites currently. The only way to get the sites total storage is to get each site storage and to sum.